# Result in decimals?

Tags: php, mysql, rows, decimal

Alright so I've been trying to make two values in two different tables add up to one number. Its for posting and comments how many a user has done. The `.$Author['id'].` reads from another php file and is fine how it is.

When I use the code below it all works but the numbers are in decimals. So if `$result` has a value of 4 and `$result2` is 2 it would come up saying 0.6. I have made sure that there is nothing wrong with the results or num_rows by replacing the `echo` with `echo "$num_rows";` and it comes up with the right result. But why do when I try to add these together they become a decimal?

```
<?php

$link = mysql_connect("--------", "---------", "--------");
mysql_select_db("--------", $link);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM post_threads WHERE author = '".$Author['id']."'", $link);
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

$result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM post_comments WHERE userid = '".$Author['id']."'", $link);
$num_rows2 = mysql_num_rows($result2);

$a = array(".$num_rows." + ".$num_rows2.");
echo "" . array_sum($a) . "\n";

?>
```

Comment: Can you explain what you are doing in the last two lines of code?

Comment: If you want an integer use `round($value);`

Comment: You're getting `0.6` because you're putting `.` before the number when you write `".$num_rows."`. Why are you turning them into decimal fractions if you just want to add the integers?

Answer (score 1):

You have to change this line:

```
$a = array(".$num_rows." + ".$num_rows2.");
echo "" . array_sum($a) . "\n";
```

to:

```
$a =$num_rows + $num_rows2;
echo $a. "\n";
```

if you want to use an array, (I dont know why), should be:

```
$a = array($num_rows,$num_rows2);
echo array_sum($a) . "\n";
```

Closing the variables in quotes, you are converting them to string

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you meant with the last 2 lines of your code, but I suggest the following:

```
$a = array($num_rows, $num_rows2);
echo array_sum($a) . "\n";
```

Hope that works out for you